# How to get access to the current JUnitCore to add a listener?

Tags: ant, junit, task

I have some test infrastructure classes that I'd like to add as listeners of JUnitCore , specifically for testRunFinished.
I'm invoking Junit 4 from ant's  task.

Is there some way for me to get access to the JUnitCore created by the  task so that I can add a listener?

Answer (score 2):

Not from ant's junit task.

You best write a main method that runs your test suite "manually".

```
package test;

import org.junit.runner.Request;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.Runner;
import org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener;
import org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier;

public class RollYourOwnTestRun {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runner runner = Request.classes(StackTest.class).getRunner();
        RunNotifier notifier = new RunNotifier();
        Result result= new Result();
        RunListener listener= result.createListener();
        notifier.addListener(listener);
        notifier.addListener(...); // add your listener
        notifier.fireTestRunStarted(runner.getDescription());
        runner.run(fNotifier);
        notifier.fireTestRunFinished(result);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A [@RunWith](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/runner/RunWith.html) annotation could help (with some minor API best-practice violations): you give your own Runner, and override `run(RunNotifier notifier)`. Through the RunNotifier, you may use the add*Listener-API, which is marked as internal only currently. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late, but you might try wrapping your `RunListener` into ant's `JUnitResultFormatter` (from `org.apache.ant:ant-junit`):

```
import static org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitVersionHelper.getTestCaseClassName;
import static org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitVersionHelper.getTestCaseName;
import static org.junit.runner.Description.createTestDescription;

public class MyJunitFormatter implements JUnitResultFormatter {

private final MyListener delegate = new MyListener();

@Override
@SneakyThrows(Exception.class)
public void endTest(Test test) {
    delegate.testFinished(
            createTestDescription(
                    getTestCaseClassName(test),
                    getTestCaseName(test)));
}

// ....
```

See https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-user/201009.mbox/%3C86A2FB65A5F8B549A8E8939DC00F8269332B4A@exchange03.nexus.commercehub.com%3E